# How to write nested JSON in php from mysql response with active record

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I have a PHP query built in  active record and want to get a nested JSON response.

I am using Codeigniter MVC as my PHP Framework.

In my **Controller**:

```
$data['all_json'] = $this->json_model->get_my_json($var1);

$result_array = array();

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $result_array[] = array();
}

exit;
```

In my **Model** is this query:

```
public function get_my_json($var1) 
{
    $this->db->select('column1,column2,column3');
    $this->db->from('table');
    $this->db->where('column1',$var1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    print json_encode($result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

I want to built a JSON documentation more like something below:

Below is the regular return:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "column1",
        "price": column2,
        "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
        "warehouseLocation": {
            "latitude": column3,
            "longitude": column4
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "column1",
        "price": column2,
        "warehouseLocation": {
            "latitude": column3,
            "longitude": column4
        }
    }
]
```

And the corresponding schema doc:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "title": "Product set",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "title": "Product",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
                "type": "number"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "price": {
                "type": "number",
                "exclusiveMinimum": 0
            },
            "dimensions": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "length": {"type": "number"},
                    "width": {"type": "number"},
                    "height": {"type": "number"}
                },
                "required": ["length", "width", "height"]
            },
            "warehouseLocation": {
                "description": "Coordinates of the warehouse with the product",
                "$ref": "http://json-schema.org/geo"
            }
        },
        "required": ["id", "name", "price"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Build an array with the structure you want, and then [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it.

Comment: I gonna try this, haven't thought about this simple thing.

Comment: i got it done. Thanks to your suggestion.